# Heroku: Migrating form shared database to clear database

Tags: database, heroku

I am trying to migrate the heroku shared database from app1 to clearDB in app2 and i get the following error message:
$ heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE "app1 database url" --app app2 
DATABASE_URL does not match any of your databases

DATABASE (DATABASE_URL) <---restore--- b002.dump

! invalid format 
! or to_url must be a postgres URL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a postgres backup against a MySQL database.

The only way to do this is via taps which pushes the data through activerecord.  More information here:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/taps

Comment: pgbackups lets you restore from postgres to mysql?

Comment: Thanks Folks. Much appreciate it. Will try Taps